# SSO for Composite Apps using SAML or OAuth

Tags: oauth2, single-sign-on, oauth, saml, composite-app

We have a SaaS running on AWS that we want to integrate with Salesforce. In a first step we want to add a web tab to the Salesforce UI and have a single-sign-on with our application so that if somebody logs into Salesforce and they go to the web tab with our application they are automatically logged in there as well.

I have read about SSO for Composite Apps (https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Single_Sign_On_for_Composite_Apps), but that uses session_id as a parameter and a SOAP call to authenticate the user, which doesn't sound like current best practices. I would have expected to use the standard SAML or OAuth to authenticate the user.

Questions is: is passing the session_id and server_url to my composite app the current best practice to achieve SSO with a composite app, or can I do this using SAML or OAuth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow - that page is REALLY old. I just started the ball rolling on removing it.

If you just need SSO to your app, you should use SAML or OAuth. If you also need to call back into Force.com APIs, then look at [Canvas](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Force.com_Canvas).